# pyinstaller exe gives fopen error, is there a way to troubleshoot this

Tags: python, pyinstaller, rest

UPDATE: Apparently it was environment I was compiling in. I installed a fresh environment on a different computer and worked with no issue. I believe I'll start using 2-3 environments so I can test just incase its something with the one I'm coding on.

I have compiled the below program into a exe. as I understand part of this error is that it can not find the file. I have put copies of the referenced file in every spot I can think of just to get the exe to work correctly once so I can understand what I need to do to correct the path. But it just gives the error below when ran in command line.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pathlib import Path
import os, sys
response = requests.get('url', headers={'CERT': 'cert'}).json()
json2 = json.dumps(response)
filename = '/untitled5/data.json'
if '_MEIPASS2' in os.environ:
    filename = os.path.join(os.environ['_MEIPASS2'], filename)
fd = open(filename, 'wb')
f = fd
f.write(json2)
f.close()
```

This fucntions beuatifully in my Jupyter lab. But the exe gives this:

```
Failed to decode wchar_t from UTF-8
MultiByteToWideChar: The data area passed to a system call is too small.
share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\.cache\terser-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512\2e\ba\cfce62ec1f408830c0335f2b46219d58ee5b068473e7328690e542d2f92f2058865c600d845a2e404e282645529eb0322aa4429a84e189eb6b58c1b97c1a could not be extracted!
fopen: No such file or directory
```

I have tried working backwards with the fopen issue and then forward with the failed to decode issue and have made no head way. I'm starting to wonder if it is even possible to write an exe that uses a rest API to call and store data. Or if there is a way to configure Windows to run the py script without python fully installed. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Apparently it was environment I was compiling in. I installed a fresh environment on a different computer and worked with no issue. I believe I'll start using 2-3 environments so I can test just incase its something with the one I'm coding on.